# facebook authentication error

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I am Developing a simple Facebook Application in php which displays only name of the user of the application.

Facebook authentication dialog that appears whenever a facebook user joins an app is not appearing with the programming code I dowloaded from link https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk officially provided at facebook app developer page.

I have dowloaded some other app codes which has wrong authentication code. 
I am facing 2-3 errors, in some cases the canvas page of the application is refreshing itself again and again and in the other case authentication window appears, but when one clicks on "Allow App" the page is redirected to application page that is loaded on the server and on clicking "Don't Allow" the page is redirected to canvas page instead of coming back to home page of user.

is the php-sdk library that i have downloaded is outdated or there is any other problem.

please anybody who has tested code provide the with solution coz i have tried a lot of readymade applications already (all has sane problems). i just require a working authentication code with correct php library

Comment: you have to post the error messages, also have you tried the example https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples

Comment: As @Krish said, what are the error...what *code* are you using? share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

THe source code from the official PHP sdk site is working.... yet, it is expected that in the provided sample code, the authentication flow is not kicked off automatically.  You can verify that by going through the code.

there are a few community generated tutorial listed in http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=79787.  You may find them useful.